# Outdated Ruby GEM, How Do I Share My Changes?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

So I have been playing with a Ruby gem for a work project that [manipulates and extracts data from PDF documents](http://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-toolkit).  I wanted to change a method to parallel another, since the functionality was limited.  I am not a Ruby expert by any stretch, just started learning two weeks ago, but this is boilerplate.  I checked the [the RubyForge page](http://rubyforge.org/projects/pdf-toolkit/), and tried searching [GitHub for the project, to find basically nothing](http://github.com/search?q=pdf-toolkit&type=Everything&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1).  So the question is, where do I go with a potential patch, since the RF page has a patch and a bug I looked at, and activity seems to have stopped a few years ago.  Do I just fork and start using GitHub like I planned to?  Do I contact RubyForge somehow and ask for assistance (I do not think I have the skills yet to own the project), or do I follow up with [RubyGems.org](http://rubygems.org/gems/pdf-toolkit)?  A little research on StackOverflow and other places makes it unclear how I should proceed, and I am an obvious amateur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an opinion, but if the project is not active anymore, and the license allows for forking, I would go ahead with it. As long as you mention the original source, I wouldn't see any problems with starting your own. What do other people think?

Comment: Thanks for the encouraging words.  My bigger issue is that I see a proper fork as a responsibility, one that is pretty silly considering I will change only five lines of code and have insufficient scripting knowledge to troubleshoot other bugs (several are open, specifcally one that prevents the toolkit being used on any newish Ruby release on Windows Vista/7).  Does this mean I should gear for GitHub?

Comment: @alharaka No need to think a fork is a huge burden. Forking to a github repo doesn't mean you're the new maintainer of the old project. Just fork and make your changes. Down the line if people have patches/bugs just politely mention your lack of time and encourage them to fork and provide patches. If even that is too much ask the first interested party if they'd like to be the maintainer.

Comment: Thanks to all for the encouragement. I am going to figure out how to properly fork it on GitHub, then push my personalized gem, if this is considered good practice, to Gemcutter.